# SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW Chathead with android M - app crashs

Tags: android, chat, android-windowmanager

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/txusballesteros/bubbles-for-android).

and I know it can run on android M, but for some reason it crashes everytime with my project.

I tried researching and adding permission `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` (even tho it's not required) and i'm stuck.

Anyone know why it crashes?

```
private void addViewToWindow(final BubbleBaseLayout view) {
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
crashes here >>> getWindowManager().addView(view, view.getViewParams());
}
});
}
```

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ce82da -- permission denied for this
>   window type

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue, just not the usual way(as in manifest).
This is the solution i found on a different thread:

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

Run this through your activity, prior to creation of bubbles.